# Aggregated case

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have the 2 aggregate functions for a case statement
i need to get count and sales for different flags of the customer

Basic Query:

```
Select count(distinct invoices), sum(tot_sal_amt) from stores
```

Trying:

```
    Select date,case count(invoices)
when (sum(case when custom_flag='guest' then tot_sal_amt  end)then count(invoices) end 
when (sum(case when custom_flag='non-guest' then tot_sal_amt  end)then count(invoices) end 
when (sum(case when custom_flag is null then tot_sal_amt  end)then count(invoices) end
from stores
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you need group by custom_flag

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible provided you use such like format below :

```
select date,
       custom_flag,
       (case 
        when sum(case when custom_flag='guest' then tot_sal_amt end) then count(distinct invoices) 
        when sum(case when custom_flag='non-guest' then tot_sal_amt end) then count(distinct invoices) 
        when sum(case when custom_flag is null then tot_sal_amt  end) then count(distinct invoices) 
       end) as cnt_invoices,
       (case 
        when custom_flag='guest' then sum(tot_sal_amt)
        when custom_flag='non-guest' then sum(tot_sal_amt) 
        when custom_flag is null then sum(tot_sal_amt)
       end) as sum_tot_sal_amt      
  from stores
 group by date, custom_flag;
```

*The problem occurs for*

1. `case count(invoices) when` where
   `count(invoices)` should be removed.
2. the extra opening parentheses in front of `sum` statements.

**But** there's non need to use `case..when` statements for your case, since *for all cases the results are equal*, so using the following is enough :

```
 select date,
       custom_flag,
       count(distinct invoices) as cnt_invoices,
       sum(tot_sal_amt) as sum_tot_sal_amt 
  from stores
 group by date, custom_flag;
```

[*Rextester Demo*](https://rextester.com/JQSN92141)

Comment: Illegal expression in when clause of case Expression- Error i am getting when trying

Comment: `when sum(case when custom_flag='guest' then tot_sal_amt  end)` is missing a condition

Answer (score 0):

You can have two or more aggregate functions in the same `case` statement, but you cannot retreive more than one value.

Pseudo-code not tested.

```
Select  date
       ,Count(distinct invoices)
       ,Count(Case when custom_flag='guest'     then invoices
                   when custom_flag='non-guest' then invoices
                   when custom_flag is null then invoices end) as cnt_invoices
       ,Sum(Case when custom_flag='guest' then tot_sal_amt
                 when custom_flag='non-guest' then tot_sal_amt
                 when custom_flag is null then tot_sal_amt end) as sum_sal_amt
from stores
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want conditional aggregation:

```
Select date, 
       count(distinct invoiceid) as num_invoices,
       count(distinct case when custom_flag = 'guest' then invoiceid end) as guest_invoices,
       count(distinct case when custom_flag = 'non-guest' then invoiceid end) as nonguest_invoices,
       count(distinct case when custom_flag is null then invoiceid end) as null_invoices,
       sum(total_sal_amt) as total_sales,
       sum(case when custom_flag = 'guest' then total_sal_amt end) as guest_total_sal_amt,
       sum(case when custom_flag = 'non-guest' then total_sal_amt end) as nonguest_total_sal_amt,
       sum(case when custom_flag is null then total_sal_amt end) as null_total_sal_amt
from stores
group by date;
```

Or more simply:

```
Select date, custom_flag,
       count(distinct invoiceid) as num_invoices,
       sum(total_sal_amt) as total_sales,
from stores
group by date, custom_flag;
```